# Show swiper slide based on ACF Repeater sub field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, swiper.js

Basically I have ACF Repeater field as shown below

[image]

I also have a variable with value of the user's location.

So for instance, if user's location variable value is set to A, I want to show the slide which has 'region' field value set to 'A'.

Here's the code I have for simple slider using swiper.

```
<div class="container-fluid container-fluid-no">
<div class="row alto-bg">
    <div class="col-lg-12 px-0">
        <div class="row first-slider">
            <div class="col-lg-12 swiper-container px-0 mx-0">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <?php
                        if( have_rows('slider') ):
                            while ( have_rows('slider') ) : the_row(); ?>  
                                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background- 
      image:url('<?php echo the_sub_field('background_image'); ?>');">
                                    <div class="row slide-content">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="pt-3 ">
                                                <?php 
     the_sub_field('slide_content');?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-overlay"></div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endwhile;
                        else :
                        endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                <script>
                    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                        direction: 'horizontal',
                        loop: true,
                        effect: 'fade',
                        pagination: {
                            el: '.swiper-pagination',
                            clickable: true,
                        },
                        keyboard: {
                            enabled: true,
                        },
                        navigation: {
                            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                        }
                    })
                </script>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<div>
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What is "user's location variable"? You want to slide to a specific slide or only show slider where subfield matching location variable?

Comment: @Artem I want to show specific slide based on the user location value. So for e.g. Let's say I have $userLocation = "A", I only want slide with region 'A' selected. Hope that makes sense.